# Compling html files

Tags: html, compiler-construction

Are HTML files compiled? If yes, which compiler is used? If no then how does the browser find any errors?

Answer (score 5):

HTML files are not compiled; they could be said to be interpreted.

The raw HTML file data (mark-up text) is pushed / pulled down the wire to the client / browser upon request which then, using its own engine implementation (for the most part, and if the client is a visual rendering browser) will render the contents as it sees fit.

This is why while one *thing* might work as desired in, say, Chrome, that same *thing* could potentially be rendered unexpectedly by other clients - For example, IE has been made notorious for inventing its own way of processing mark-up and neglecting the 'standard', but the MS team now seem to be coming to their senses.

The client / browser finds errors just as a compiler would at compile time, only at what could be labelled as runtime. *It* knows what can be handled by its own means and can therefore report it. And at this point the client already has the data, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not "compiled."  It's delivered to the client (in most cases a web browser) and "rendered" in some way by that client (in most cases as a visual web page in a web browser).

There are various [rendering engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browser_engines) used by various browsers.  Errors are determined and handled by the rendering engines.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated, HTML is not compiled.

However, confusingly enough, Microsoft has a help format called [Compiled HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) (.CHM). Although, this isn't compiled in the same sense as a computer program is compiled, but more "compiled" like a book is compiled. In other words, this is just a single file representation of many HTML files.